# 'Singleton' per thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I have a question about an issue I encountered. I'm trying to implement a object (singleton) / thread, but I encountered a behaviour that I did not expect.

For example, we have the following code

```
class Persistence

  attr_accessor :data

  def self.instance
    Thread.current[:persistence_store] ||= Persistence.new
  end

  def self.clear
    Thread.current[:persistence_store] = nil
  end

  def get_data(user_id = nil)
    self.data ||= AnotherClass.get_advanced_data(user_id)
  end

end
```

Lets say a request comes in, and we have `Persistence.instance.get_data(1)` in the controller, (thus get_data is execute once).

Then we do `Persistence.instance.get_data` in a model again, all works as expected it loads the data, from the initial request.

But lets say in 5 minutes a user does the same request. I found out that the value saved in `Persistence.instance.get_data(2)` is the value from the first user request. (Its actually `Persistence.instance.get_data(1)`).

Doesn't rails create a new thread per request, that the above case should not occure?

The only solution I found out was to add a before_filter in application controller that does `Persistence.clear`, then all works as expected..

I'm a bit confused why this behaviour should occur. Hope you understand my question.

Thank you!

Comment: _Doesn't rails create a new thread per request, that the above case should not occure? (sic)_

It does NOT create new thread per request. It creates a new instance of the controller per request but not a new thread. Hope this clears up any confusion.

Comment: Thank you @TedPrice, I suspected this was the case, but.. a couple of posts got me very confused.

Comment: Wouldn't the session object be a good place to store temporary per user data?

Comment: @Kris, for my case no, because I have a API base application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails, creates a new instance of the Controller per request, not a thread. The best solution I found was: https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store

Comment: Some web servers will opt to handle multiple requests at once by creating more threads and/or more processes. But as a minimum there will be at least one process and one thread.